# Initialize stat after await in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an async submit function which sends data to the server. now I want to whenever submitted user stay this page but state gets back to initial form.
here is my code :

```
save = async () => { 
....
await rest.post('some_where', {data})
// here
// this.setState({cart: [], selectedItems: []});
}
```

i want to exactly after sending rest request state initialize again; not before that. 
how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) Promise method?

> The `then()` method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

This means you can do:

```
save = async () => { 
  ....
  await rest.post('some_where', {data}).then(() => {
    this.setState({cart: [], selectedItems: []});
  });
}
```

---

If something goes south and your promise fails, you can do another set of logic. Perhaps show this on your UI:

```
save = async () => { 
  ....
  await rest.post('some_where', {data}).then(() => {
    this.setState({cart: [], selectedItems: []});
  }, () => {
    console.error("Post failed!");
    this.setState({didFail: true});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

post call returns a promise and you need to add a resolver callback and then you can call setState({}) method. In your case, setState method will not have updated data from server.